# How to Hide the Default Custom actions from SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, context-menu

I was created a custom list. But by default custom actions are present in Context menu. I want to hide the Custom actions like Workflows, Alert me Shared with and Delete Item from list using C# or element.xml file.

[image]

Comment: pls share your support by upvoting/marking as answer

Answer (score 1):

**Done**, Write below custom script using script editor web part on your SP List

```
<style type=text/css>
a[title="Share"]{
display: none;
}
</style>
```

I have hidden "Share" list item menu. refer screen shot

[image]

call me one liner ;)